# error on checkout in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, error

[image]

{"message":"Please agree to all the terms and conditions before placing the order."}

I have tried everything but still, face issue. can anyone guide me?[image]

Comment: Can you include the screenshot of headers

Comment: Hi can anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: Are you using checkmo payment method? Have you customized them to get the additional fields?

Comment: no, but want to customize, if its working fine then, I will do that.